# Django - Consuming a RESTful service asynchronously

Tags: python, django, rest

I need to create a django web portal in which users can select and run ad-hoc reports by providing values, via forms, to parameters defined in each specific report.  The view that processes the user’s report execution requests needs to make RESTFul service calls to a remote Jasper Reports Server where the actual output is generated.

I have already written the client to make the RESTful service calls to the remote server. Depending on how large the report is the service calls can take several minutes.

What is the best method for making the service call after the user’s form has been validated so that the call processes asynchronously (in the background) and the user can continue you use the web portal while their report is being generated.

Do I need to make an AJAX call when the parameters form is submitted or should I start a new thread for the RESTful client in the view after the form has validated? Or something else?

Comment: It looks like I need to research Celery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

django-celery is a popular choice for async tasks, i usually use greenlets as im used to them.

Then to notify the user you can use the notification framework to tell the client that something is done.